# Recursion: Unsure of the callback function's value during the iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

The following code is a recursive algorithm that simply sums the integers in an array. The code works, but I'm not sure why. In the code below there is a return statement:
    return  my_array.pop() + array_sum(my_array);

My question is what values does **array_sum(my_array)** take during each iteration? I cannot console.log those values on Visual Studio Code because I get stack overflow errors, and the debugging tool's values do not make sense. I won't waste your time with them unless you feel it's necessary. Here's the code"

```
function array_sum(my_array) {
    if (my_array.length === 1) {
        return my_array[0];
    }
    else {
      return my_array.pop() + array_sum(my_array);
    }
};

console.log(array_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

I know what my_array.pop() produces: 6, then 5, then 4, and so on, but I do not know how the sum is produced. Some explanation would be very helpful. This particular output is 21 as it should be. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note,  while recursion can be fun,  it can also be an unnecessary strain on resources. Every time a new instance of your function is called,  the computer has to save the state of the old instance on the "stack" (a special region of memory) which can slow things down and make debugging difficult (as you've discovered). Typically,  if it can be avoided,  it should. For example,  your code can be easily done with a reduce method: var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

Comment: Yes,, I know there are much easier and straight forward ways to accomplish challenges in JavaScript, but I need to get comfortable with recursion. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focus on the return statement of the non base case:

```
return my_array.pop() + array_sum(my_array);
```

For the first call, this says to return `6` plus the recursive call of the original array with the last element popped, i.e. it can be rewritten as this:

```
return 6 + array_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

The above call to `array_sum()` will in turn become:

```
5 + array_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

So now the final sum looks like this:

```
6 + 5 + array_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This continues until `array_sum()` receives an array with just one element in it.  In this *base case*, it just returns that number, without recursing again.  So the final sum just becomes:

```
6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21
```

Comment: So it's really the my_array.pop() values that are being summed. There are no values associated with arr_sum(my_array). It is simply a call statement that takes progressively smaller lengths of my_array.